# Verificar Tamanho do Input e exibir label de acordo com expressão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função que verifica se um campo for menor que 3 ao dar foco (clicar) no input `Email`.

Resumindo:

Se CPF e RG for menor que 3, exibe a `label[for="label-custom-field2"]` e `label[for="label-custom-field3`

Se Apenas RG for menor que 3, exibe a `label[for="label-custom-field3"]` e esconde a`label[for="label-custom-field2`.

Se Apenas CPF for menor que 3, exibe a `label[for="label-custom-field2"]` e esconde a`label[for="label-custom-field3`.

Porém mesmo que o RG esteja preenchido ao dar foco no campo email, a `label[for="label-custom-field3` é exibida.

[Veja o código aqui](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/rLQyRQ).

Comment: Acho esse tipo de coisa mais fácil a se fazer com Angular :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters em angular seria mais fácil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal alguma coisa como este [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/rwb6yc8e/)?

Você pode retornar falso na função e exibir o que quiser de acordo com algum parâmetro do tipo data- do campo texto.

Tente seguir [este artigo](http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2012/11/21/html5-form-validation/) que pode facilitar.